# show/hide json data on mouse click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HskvW.png) i have a Json data which contains various video url and i want to show the video on mouse click on a respective link and wants to hide the rest of video url at the same time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ure43.png)

Here as shown in my third image, i want that if i am clicking on angular1 link then, the rest of the data that is  angular2 must get hide and i should only see the video that i have in angular1 but i am unable to do that.

Comment: Will you please post some code. What have you tried?

Comment: okk..i am sending wat i have tried

Comment: $scope.showV=function(videodetails){
            $scope.show1=true;
            if(videodetails.linkName==true){
                $scope.linkName = linkName;

Comment: @alok please add in the main PO

Comment: please add you working demo in snippet so that we know what you actually want to achieve and whats gong wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: i have described that in my next image

Comment: just having a look at image doesn't help to understand your problem add a working demo Refer this for asking question help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

well Alok as per your image it seems like you wanted a expand collapsable menu and when user click on that data bind accordingly and rest of the data (div) hide, have a look at the below link :

```
" https://codepen.io/jasoncluck/pen/iDcbh "
```

I hope it helps.